# How Do I List the Users who haven't posted in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a requirement for our system to list all members that HAVE posted a coupon and all the users that HAVEN'T posted a coupon.  I made an SQL script to pull the list of members who HAVE posted a coupon. Here is the code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
b.Email,
b.FirstName,
b.LastName,
b.MemberDisplayName AS DisplayName,
b.MemberID
FROM ClassAd a
INNER JOIN Member b ON b.MemberID = a.MemberID
WHERE a.PostType = 'CPN'
AND DATEDIFF(d, 0, GETDATE()) <= a.ExpirationDate
AND a.Viewable = 'Y'
AND b.SystemID = 1
AND b.Claimed = 'Y'
AND b.Email IS NOT NULL
```

How do I reverse this script so it pulls only the users who HAVEN'T posted a coupon..?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The coupon is represented by ClassAd?

Comment: how do you differentiate the  HAVEN'T posted a coupon or have posted a coupon ?  so from your above query i see a.PostType = 'CPN' means if PostType  is CPN then it means have posted coupon . Am i right? do you have other Post types ? That is necessary to answer ur question

Comment: Yes, 'CPN' represents a coupon. I want all members from the 'Member' table to show that have no records in the 'ClassAd' table with a 'CPN'.  Is that clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List of Members who *have* posted a coupon.

```
SELECT Email
     , FirstName
     , LastName
     , MemberDisplayName As DisplayName
     , MemberID
FROM   Member
WHERE  SystemID = 1
AND    Claimed = 'Y'
AND    Email IS NOT NULL
AND    EXISTS (
         SELECT *
         FROM   ClassAd
         WHERE  PostType = 'CPN'
         AND    ExpirationDate >= DateDiff(dd, 0, Current_Timestamp)
         AND    Viewable = 'Y'
         AND    MemberID = Member.MemberID
       )
```

To reverse the logic it would be a simple case of making it a `NOT EXISTS`!

Comment: It is strange that the others solutions did not work for you. They should be equivalent up to the Current_Timestamp vs. GETDATE().

Comment: @FabianBüttner `Current_Timestamp` is equivalent to `GetDate()` in SQL Server. In fact I believe SQL Server resolves them both to `GetDate()` internally. I choose to use `Current_Timestamp` as it is a more portable standard.

Answer (score 2):

An outer join and test for null is the opposite of the join
Note you need outer join to use on (not where)

```
SELECT DISTINCT
b.Email,
b.FirstName,
b.LastName,
b.MemberDisplayName AS DisplayName,
b.MemberID
FROM Member b  
Left Outer JOIN ClassAd a
  ON b.MemberID = a.MemberID
 AND a.PostType = 'CPN'
 AND DATEDIFF(d, 0, GETDATE()) <= a.ExpirationDate
 AND a.Viewable = 'Y'
 AND b.SystemID = 1
 AND b.Claimed = 'Y'
 AND b.Email IS NOT NULL
where a.MemberID is null
```

You could move the

```
 AND b.SystemID = 1
 AND b.Claimed = 'Y'
 AND b.Email IS NOT NULL
```

into the where but in this format the query optimizer has a chance to eliminate rows before the join

Comment: This query wouldn't work, he does want to see those members that have no coupons (classAd), so by definition, it won't be any ClassAd records which is the main table in your query, so it will always be empty (at least as per my understanding).

Comment: @pedromarce Then you don't understand a left outer join

Answer (score 1):

Something like this (untested) should do it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
b.Email,
b.FirstName,
b.LastName,
b.MemberDisplayName AS DisplayName,
b.MemberID
FROM Member b
WHERE b.MemberID NOT IN 
     (SELECT a.MemberID 
        FROM ClassAd a
       WHERE a.PostType = 'CPN'
         AND DATEDIFF(d, 0, GETDATE()) <= a.ExpirationDate
         AND a.Viewable = 'Y')
AND b.SystemID = 1
AND b.Claimed = 'Y'
AND b.Email IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: please add a FROM to your sub-query - I will fix my solution, too (missed to push a.PostType = 'CPN' into the sub-query) ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, no results are returned, which is not possible

Comment: Then please specify more clearly what you want. both suggested answers simply turn the "exists" of a corresponding ClassAd row, as specified by the original query, into a "not exists", the predicate remains the same.

Comment: This query will reverse the one you asked for, if there are no results you will need to find out where is the condition that is not correct now (maybe some of the criteria for Member are now not necessary) or some other reasons, but here what it is doing is getting all members where systemId = 1 and claimed = "Y" (maybe this is wrong in this case?) and email is not null and also that doesn't have a classAd record linked to it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming having a coupon is represented by table ClassAd, you can use NOT IN and a sub-query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
b.Email,
b.FirstName,
b.LastName,
b.MemberDisplayName AS DisplayName,
b.MemberID
FROM Member b 
WHERE
b.memberID NOT IN (SELECT a.MemberID FROM ClassAd a WHERE  a.PostType = 'CPN' AND DATEDIFF(d, 0, GETDATE()) <= a.ExpirationDate AND a.Viewable = 'Y')
AND b.SystemID = 1
AND b.Claimed = 'Y'
AND b.Email IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no results are returned, which is not possible

Comment: It is strange that the accepted solution did not work for you. The ones of @pedro and and mine should be equivalent, up to the Current_Timestamp vs. GETDATE().

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM @Member a
LEFT JOIN @ClassAd b 
    ON a.MemberId = b.MemberId AND b.PostType = 'CPN'
        AND b.ExpirationDate >= GETDATE()
        AND b.Viewable = 'Y'
WHERE b.MemberId IS NULL
AND a.SystemId = 1
AND a.Claimed = 'Y'
```